ArcGIS Pro doesn't see loaded DWG geodatabase
I would like to load my DWG file to ArcGIS Pro and convert it to the geodatabase file.
Unfortunately, I have the problem. I am new to the ArcGIS Pro and watched this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8sbUMDbYVI
where everything works well, unlike on my desktop.
After loading the DWG file to ArcGIS Pro I saw the message, that everything was right. However, I can't see anything neither on my map nor in the database, which remains empty. Not to mention, that I can't change the name of the geodatabase.

After "successfully" loading the DWG file, I still see the base map with no option to see the CAD layers.
Why aren't my CAD files visible at all?

first rule of geodatabase names > * Do not attempt to use spaces, SQL keywords or special characters in object names.
https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/what-are-the-recommended-naming-conventions-for-geodata-000006254 keep it simple.

Even without spaces it doesn't work

According to your screenshot the tool is exporting to OSGB which is the UK but your map is centred on Germany... Have a look at the UK?

This is only the base map in WHS84. I can center it anywhere, it doesn't matter.

It's WGS84 you meant to say and showing the basemap centred on "anywhere" is, I hope you can see, misleading to say the least when the output is being exported to OSGB. There is not enough information to help you, I think if you shared the DWG file, others can explore why its not displaying.

To use a DWG file, follow these steps: 1. First, load the DWG file into the map. Then, zoom to the layer to check if the data is visible. If it is visible, proceed to the next step.


Select the specific layers you want to export, export the data, and configure the coordinate system of your CAD drawing in the export environment. Note: If your drawing is not created based on a real coordinate system, the exported data locations will be incorrect.



Check if the data display is correct at your chosen export location. If there are no issues, the process is complete.


Everything would be fine, but the file must be georeferenced in AutoCAD
